# What if ISP's block port 8332?

Tags: bitcoind, port

Hypothetically, if it were a well coordinated NSA-type shut down and ALL ISP's suddenly blocked port 8332 (major ones anyway), how would the Bitcoin system immediately handle it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bitcoin can be configured to handle any port for both peer-to-peer communication, as well as JSON RPCs. However, as Bitcoin clients do not encrypt their messages, it would still be fairly easy to filter out Bitcoin-related activities. One could then switch to using Bitcoin through TOR, or the developers could implement message encryption if needed be.

Answer (score 3):

We would all switch to port 80.

Comment: Port 80 is HTTP standard; many servers running Bitcoin are also running websites, so I doubt that would work. AFAIK, though, just switching ports in the client software would work.

Comment: Yes, mostly my answer was to illustrate the futility of trying to kill Bitcoin by port blocking.